# Как выйти из цикла в коде на jQuery?

Tags: jquery

См. вопрос в комменте в коде:

```
var flagFormEmpty = true;
$(function() {
    $('#myForm input:button').click(function() {
        $('#myForm input[type=text]').each(function() {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') {
                flagFormEmpty = false;

// можно ли здесь как-то выйти из цикла? т.е. если мы нашли хоть одно заполненное поле, то дальше проверять не надо ...

            }
        });
        if (flagFormEmpty) {
            alert('Не заполнено ни одно поле');
            return false;
        }
        // do something
    });
});
```

И наверное можно переписать этот код покрасивше/оптимальнее. Подскажите как, если знаете вариант лучше :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать так, чтобы jQuery сам подсчитал число заполненных полей:

```
var fields = $('input[type=text]').not('[value=""]').length     
alert('Заполнено полей: '+ fields);
```

[Здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/498fK/) можно посмотреть, как работает этот пример.

Comment: супер! если можно было еще протримить поля как в моем примере перед тем как их считать ... :)

Comment: Вот селектор с кастомным условием. 
$('input[type=text]').filter(function(i){return $.trim(this.value)!=''; })

Comment: =) спасибо :) то, что нужно!

Answer (score 5):

Из цикла выйти можно через return false;

```
var flagFormEmpty = true;
$(function() {
    $('#myForm input:button').click(function() {
        $('#myForm input[type=text]').each(function() {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') {
                flagFormEmpty = false;
                return false;     //Больше цикл гоняться не будет
            }
        });

    if (flagFormEmpty ) {
        alert('Не заполнено ни одно поле');
        return false;
    }
    // do something
});

});
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это будет выход из функции в цикле, но не из самого цикла.

Comment: А какая разница, из функции или из цикла, если в самой конструкции each не предусмотрено выполнение ничего, кроме callback-функции ? Вот, дока говорит, что return false в callback-функции в each аналогично оператору break - так оно и получается. http://jquery-docs.ru/Core/each/

Comment: спасибо return false - буду знать :)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1: можно в цикле установить флаг и проверять на каждой итерации. Но тогда функция все равно пробежится по всем элементам (хотя и ничего не будет с ними делать).
Вариант 2: написать свою функцию через document.getElementsByTagName(). Кода больше, результат что нужен.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. 1 вариант не катит - из цикла надо выйти, не зачем его гонять, если смысла нет - неправильно это :)
второй вариант тоже не подходит - я конечно могу написать это на обычном javascript'е и выйти из цикла по break, но хочу, чтобы код был именно на jquery.